# CiviCRM on MariaDB instead of mySQL

Tags: database

Has anyone run CiviCRM on MariaDB instead of mySQL

https://mariadb.org/

Running CiviCRM on MariaDB could provide significant speed improvements.

Answer (score 3):

We have mariadb on our newest server, it's a completely transparent replacement. I haven't noticed any major speed change, either better or worse, so I'd take your hope of major speed gain with a pinch of salt.

We switched to it mostly because they seem to do a better job at pushing new features than oracle... and because it looks like 100% the same, as viewed from civi

Comment: I've had a similar experience, using MariaDB 5.5 for the last year and a half for a lot of sites. I've been waiting on MariaDb10 out of caution. Switching on a live server - your experience will likely depend on your OS flavour. I did hit a few gotchas in terms of the default my.cnf configuration which are different from MySQL and MariaDB.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Maria db 10 and noticed improved stability and lower resources utilization on 3 instances.... esp memory footprint.   While it is a drop in replacement be sure to review the details about each version [compatailty](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/).  Also btw Cpanel is moving from mysql to mariadb as its preferred platform.

Comment: Thanks, Can I talk with about this?  You can see my contact  info in my profile.  Send me an email.

Answer (score 1):

We have a relatively major client in the UK (300k+ contact records / 100 users) who has swapped in Percona as we were reaching some DB connection timeouts with Mysql. It may just be related to having a better default db config with Percona then Mysql but the issues seem to have resolved. The IT manager at the client also thinks we've seen some minor performance improvements. We've been running for about a month now without any issues.