# MySql vs MariaDB

Tags: database

After some reading, it appears that MariaDB could be a better challenger to MySQL and it runs, apparently, without any problems with CiviCRM (cf [CiviCRM on MariaDB instead of mySQL](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/civicrm-on-mariadb-instead-of-mysql)).

But what about future compatibility? On the [MariaDB FAQ](https://mariadb.com/products/product-faqs?qt-faqs=2#qt-faqs) they say

> MariaDB 10 takes a different approach. While retaining close feature compatibility with MySQL, there are enough differences and enhancements so that it makes sense to start a new numbering scheme...

It's possible that in a near future, there will be too many differences between MariaDB and MySQL, and the compatibility will fall in the background. It is only a supposition.

But, will CiviCRM continue to develop only for MySQL, or could it be developed for both? Or (better for a 10-year user) for PostgreSQL? PostgreSQL, as a community driven project, is ethically closer to the Civi community than Oracle, I would think. (It's not a troll ;-)

Alongside that, some time ago, I had seen some posts about Doctrine and Civi. Has that integration gone forward?

In short: what DBMS would you advise for a new project with 200 000 contacts?

Answer (score 5):

Don't overthink it, and don't go out on a limb without a worthwhile reason.  So long as MariaDB is truly a drop-in replacement for MySQL, you're fine with that.  If somehow MariaDB ceases to be compatible, you'll be able to do an export/import to MySQL, assuming you haven't upgraded your server irreversibly *and* deleted all of your backups from before then.

As a rule of thumb, if you stick with the versions that come with the most recent couple of Ubuntu LTS releases, you'll have enough company that CiviCRM wouldn't dare leave you in the dust.

Comment: it took us about 30 min to switch from mysql to mariadb, take one, if you are not happy on how it goes at any point in the future, export, install a replacement you prefer and import.

Comment: I am running MariaDB on my local civicrm development environment for a year. And I haven't come across any issues.